# Is it possible to expect dispatch command from a non axon-class in AxonFramework

Tags: kotlin, axon

Suppose I have some classes which is not axon class (etc. Saga or agrgregate), and if I want it to dispatch command I could use command gateway, but here is the problem.  I want to write
unit testing to make sure that this non axon-class has dispatched command already. So if it's either saga or aggregate I could use fixture and then given command or event, but is it possible to use fixture with these non axon-class also.
Here is how the code looks like

```
class MyService {
    //...
    lateinit var commandGateway: CommandGateway
    fun doSomething(command: doSomethingCommand){
        commandGateway.send(command)
    }
}

class MyServiceTest {
    //...
    @Test
    fun doSomething_ShouldDispatchDoSomethingCommand(){
        // expect dispatch command from non axon-class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, Axon Framework provides Test Fixtures for Aggregates and Sagas, without specifying any additional options on the matter. The `AggregateTestFixture` does provide one method along the lines you are for, which is the `AggregateTestFixture#registerAnnotatedCommandHandler`. However, this is there to validate a component containing `@CommandHandler` annotated methods, not to validate dispatching.

Thus I think the most straightforward approach would be to mock or spy the `CommandGateway`/`CommandBus` to do the validation on to be honest.